# T-test for marketing data in excel

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, z-test, ab-test, marketing

I am currently running an A/B test, and I’m not sure how I should be arranging my data to run a t-test in excel. I have 1 control and 2 variations that I am running for an advertising campaign - the difference is only on the day when the email is sent. I'd like to run a t-test, and depending on the statistical significance, I want to decide whether to stop or continue the A/B test.
Since success, in this case, is 1 or 0, and each person only received a single email, how do I arrange my data in excel to be able to run a t-test to determine the statistical significance?

The relevant fields in the table are:

1. Unique ID of a person
2. Sign up for an account on the website (1 or 0)
3. Purchase product on the website (1 or 0)
4. Variation of the test sent to them (Test1, Test2, Control)

Comment: Given that your dependent variable is binary, ANOVA is really not appropriate since the errors will likely not be normally distributed, which is required to carry out your tests.  Instead, I'd recommend using a logistic regression.

Comment: @Stats It is unnecessary for the errors to be Normally distributed.  Indeed, ANOVA in this context is basically a test of two proportions and we all know the test *statistic* will be approximately Normally distributed for a sufficiently large sample size.

Comment: Fair point, whuber.  I forget that A/B testing typically involve huge samples.